# SQLite LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq, sqlite

I'm new to use Linq to SQL. I've read that the first step to use it - you need to create "The Object Model". It is simple for MS SQL databases. But I use SQLite and I havent't found tool to create it.
I've tried DbLinq and MONO but the first tool is too old and work only with .NET Framework 3.5 and the second tool doesn't have database add-in in windows version.

How to create this model in SQLite? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ to SQL does not work with SQLite out of the box, only SQL Server and SQL Server Compact. You must use DbLinq or maybe use Entity Framework instead (if you are brave - http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2014/11/using-sqlite-with-entity-framework-6.html )